# How to migrate Magento CE database to Magento EE?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, magento-enterprise

I'm upgrading from Magento CE (1.9.x.x) to Magento EE. How can I migrate the database? My major concern is with moving Customers, Orders, Products & Categories. I do not wish to use any additional "paid" extensions for migration of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you update to the equivalent EE version 1.14.x.x. Then there is nothing to "move". Magento Enterprise is a set of additional modules:

```
app
+-code
  +-core
    +-Mage             <-- same for CE 1.9 and EE 1.14
    +-Enterprise       <-- additional code of EE 1.14
```

So the upgrade to EE is similar to installing a bunch of extensions. You can keep your database and the setup scripts of the Enterprise modules will change anything that's necessary.